# Jquery Datatables optimize insert of multiple HTML rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

is there a better way to insert an array of HTML table rows into an existing datatable instance?

I am currently doing it like this:

```
var rows = ['<tr><td>row 1</td></tr>','<tr><td>row 2</td></tr>','<tr><td>row 3</td></tr>' ...];
$.each(rows,function(i,row){
 if(row){
  oTable.row.add($(row)).draw();
 }
});
```

It works fine but it gets really slow when dealing with more than 100 rows, it takes a minute to render 1000 rows.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: you should use modern frameworks like vuejs, reactjs etc. jquery is very old... i would recommend vuejs its easier to maintain stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found a way to optimize it, I'll leave the answer here for other people looking for the same.

Instead of:

```
var rows = ['<tr><td>row 1</td></tr>','<tr><td>row 2</td></tr>','<tr><td>row 3</td></tr>' ...];
$.each(rows,function(i,row){
 if(row){
  oTable.row.add($(row)).draw();
 }
});
```

I did this:

```
var rows = ['<tr><td>row 1</td></tr>','<tr><td>row 2</td></tr>','<tr><td>row 3</td></tr>' ...];
$.each(rows,function(i,row){
 if(row){
  oTable.row.add($(row));
 }
});
oTable.draw();
```

In other words, instead of re-drawing the table on each row insert I first added all the rows then refresh the table at the end of the loop.